# change action attribute using Javascript isn't sending to php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi try to submit user data from client side to server side by changing action attribute after validation has completed (It is something I did in the past and suddenly it is not working).
My html form(post)

```
       <!-- Submit data to server-side -->
        <form id="register" method="post">
        <table class="tableReg" border="0">
            <tr class="rowReg">
                <td>User name:</td>
                <td><input onfocus="resetColor('userID')" type="text" id="userID" name="user"></td>
                <td id=note1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowReg">
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <input onfocus="resetColor('passwordID1')" type="password" id="passwordID1" name="password1">
                </td>
                <td id=note2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowReg">
                <td>Repeat Password:</td>
                <td>
                    <input onfocus="resetColor('passwordID2')" type="password" id="passwordID2" name="password2">
                </td>
                <td id=note3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowReg">
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><input onfocus="resetColor('emailID1')" type="email" id="emailID1" name="email1"></td>
                <td id=note4></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowReg">
                <td>Repeat Email:</td>
                <td><input onfocus="resetColor('emailID2')" type="email" id="emailID2" name="email2"></td>
                <td id=note5></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <input type="button" onclick="checkInput()" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

If you see after I press the sumbit button the information is checked and if passed validation is being sent to server side, I used javaScript:

```
function checkInput(){
var regexUser = /^(?=.{1,20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;//all letters ad number and size between 1-20
var regextPwd = /^(?=.{8,8}$)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!#$%&? "]).*$/; //Password must contain 8 characters and
                                                                         // at least one number, one letter and one
                                                                         // unique character such as !#$%&?
//Email regex
var regexMail = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

var errorArr = new Array(0,0,0,0,0);

document.getElementById("register").action = "databasebuilder.php";}
```

Now after I validate input it suppose to send to databasebuilder.php which is in the same directory on my local host but it doesn't!

I already tested it without and it should be reachable why document.getElementById("register").action is not working.

Comment: Why don’t you give the URL in the action attribute in the first place? You can still validate your form and cancel submit in case there are errors. (Plase don’t say you don’t set the action from the beginning because you don’t want invalid data submitted when JS is not available – server-side validation is a __must__ anyways.)

Comment: Well I didn't really thought about validation on server-side I assume you are right. There is no point in validation of the data on Client side since someone can manipulate the script. Anyway I didn't want to submit it from the form so I could point out the invalid chars in case user is inserting wrong password and when you submit from the form the page get refreshed and input is lost unless server-side sent it back. Damn worked hours to write the validation on client side :((( stupid me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you submit the form by yourself. Like this...

```
document.getElementById("register").action = "databasebuilder.php";
document.getElementById("register").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add this in your `js function`

```
 document.getElementById("register").action= "databasebuilder.php";
 reutrn true;
```

Also change the `type` from `button` to `submit` like

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="return checkInput()" value="Submit">
```

Comment: how is it different except that it won't work in older browsers?

Comment: That is also an option but the problem with submit type is that it is reloading page preventing me from changing page contents when user entered invalid chars